# Firebird 1.5 : Compare Blob using Java

Tags: java, firebird

I need to compare the content of the blob if it already exist in the database, before saving it using Java.

Below is what I done so far :

```
 String id = "";
 String blob_name = "";
 boolean exist = false;
PreparedStatement ps = dbConBuilder.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT ID, BLOB_NAME from TBL_BLOB where BLOB_CONTENT = ?");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(getBLOB_Content().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ps.setBinaryStream(1, in, (int) getBLOB_Content().length());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getString("ID");
            blobname = rs.ge_tString("BLOB_NAME");
            exist = true;
        }
```

But I am getting `GDS Exception. 335544384. internal error` error.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if Firebird 1.5 supports comparisons of blobs, that could be a reason. Could you check the stacktrace if it contains a more specific error?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [at Firebird 1.5 error codes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/Firebird-1.5-ErrorCodes.pdf), the error code you have been given is a badblk (Bad block) meaning that your byte[] is likely to be the wrong size/form and cannot be read correctly as a ByteArrayInputStream but that is dependent on `getBLOB_Content()`

Also shouldn't the parameter index for your query be 1, not 0?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the index to 1 and the getBLOB_Content() basically returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [note](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-blob.html#langrefupd25-blob-various) in the Firebird 2.5 language reference, equality comparison of blob content is only supported since Firebird 2.0. Before that time the comparison checked if they were the same blob by using the blob ID (sort of the storage location of the blob).

Comment: Is there any sample on how to compare by blob ID?

Comment: That comparison is not really useful: blob ID is the identity of the blob. A new blob never has the same id as the old blob.

Comment: Consider upgrading to Firebird 2.5, it has only been out for three years ;)

Comment: Due to company reasons, I could not upgrade to firebird version... :( Is there any other ways to compare the blob in Firebrid 1.5?

Comment: @Ianthe FreeAdhocUDF provides a UDF that allows you to [compare blobs](http://freeadhocudf.org/documentation_english/dok_eng_blob.html#vergleichen)